# Selecting ActiveChart range to remove data labels below a value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to select the data range that is being used on an ActiveChart and filter the displayed labels to remove any that are below a specific value (in this case 0.01)

This is the code I am running:

```
  If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1) < 0.01 Then
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.Delete
  End If
```

This is definitely wrong but I am unsure how to select the "range" being used in series 1 and delete the data labels.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and any explanation about the properties of ActiveChart and why I can't call ActiveChart.Range would also really help my understanding.

Thanks in advance!

Seb

Comment: (Previously deleted comment) - you need to loop. You might also consider the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart(object)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As BigBen commented:

```vb
Dim i As Long, s As Series

Set s = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
For i = 1 To s.Points.Count
    If s.Values(i) < 0.01 Then
        s.Points(i).DataLabel.Delete
    Else
        s.Points(i).ApplyDataLabels
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you, s.points.count is what I was looking for - thanks again!